# Java Check for Calculator Program

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to java coding and need help with a check for a calculator program I'm writing! This is what I'm trying to write a check for in my program: ---> if the user has entered an incorrect formula. Example: if they type “6 + 2 +” and don’t enter a number at the end, then press “=”, there should be an alert that they need to complete the formula correctly. How would I go about checking for this? I basically have the entire calculator going, but just kind of brain shot on what to do with this.

```java
btnEqual.setOnAction(e ->     
        {

            txtOutput.appendText(" = ");
            txtTickerOutput.appendText(" = ");


            String number = "";

            for(int i = 0; i < numberStack.size(); i++)
            {
                number += numberStack.get(i);
            }

            number = number.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // get rid of whitespace 

            Integer intNumber = Integer.parseInt(number);

            intStack.push(intNumber);


            int num = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < numberStack.size(); i++)
            {

                num = intStack.get(i);


                 for(int k = 0; k <= operatorStack.size(); k++)
                {

                    // try - catch 
                    try {

                    String str = operatorStack.get(k);

                    if(str.contains("+"))
                    {
                        num += intStack.get(++i); // pre-increment operators 
                    } 


                    else if (str.contains("-"))
                    {
                        num -= intStack.get(++i);
                    } 


                    else if (str.contains("/"))
                    {
                        num /= intStack.get(++i);
                    } 


                    else if (str.contains("*"))
                    {
                        num *= intStack.get(++i);
                    }



                    } catch (Exception x)
                        {
                            x.toString();
                        }

                }
              }


              // print calculation to output 
              String calculation = String.valueOf(num);

              if (calculation.contains("=") == false)
              {
                  txtTickerOutput.appendText("Error: The formula does not contain an = sign!");
              }

              txtOutput.appendText(calculation);
              txtTickerOutput.appendText(calculation);

              // remove all elements from stacks 
              numberStack.removeAllElements();
              operatorStack.removeAllElements();
              intStack.removeAllElements();


        });
```

Comment: Do you mean Javascript or Java? Those two things are very very different. Also please share the code you tried so far so we can help.

Comment: Sorry! This is in Java, also I'm adding my code into my main post right now for my equals button setOnAction! The if statement for checking is near the bottom of the code!

Comment: Java is related to Javascript as car is to carpet.

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways to go about this depending on how your calculator functions, but an obvious way is:

If you have a formula such as `3+4+` and you want to know that it's invalid because it ends with an operation, you can do something like this:

```
String formula = "3+4+1";
String operations = "-+/%";
if(!formula.equals("")) {
  if(operations.contains(formula.substring(formula.length()-1))) {
    System.out.println("Bad operation!");
  }
}
```

The code above just checks if the last character in the formula is an operation(because it would be in the operations string). On a KeyEvent you can check for `=`, then plug in the current formula they have above and if it's a bad operation then just cancel the event and let the user know.